# Open-source command line tool for grabbing frame from video

Tags: windows, open-source, osx, video, command-line

I am looking for a 'free' command line tool that can extract frames from videos.

I looked into `ffmpeg`, `vlc`, `libav`, `avidemux`. All of them have GPL 2, requiring the user to include source code of the library in his application, which is not possible for me. I also looked into `opencv` and `imagemagick`. Both do have this feature, but both use `ffmpeg` under the hood. Without `ffmpeg`, `opencv` loses almost all its video manipulating capacity and won't be able to extract frames from most popular video types.

Is there any command line utility that will allow me to extract frame from video and also let me include it in my application without any hassle, like Boost License or MIT License?

Platform requirements - Mac and Windows.

Comment: One of the problems that you will have is that things like the MPEG algorithms are patented and that patent is enforced.  You might find https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html useful.

Comment: Yes, I read them. But why should `mpeg` algorithms be required to extract frames from all kinds of videos?

Comment: Since you don't specify which kinds of video and state you are after most of the popular types I assumed that you were looking to support most of the popular types - many of which use MPEG derived encoding.

Comment: Oh yes, true that. Many of the videos will be MP4, that is by far the most common types of video I find. Sigh. So it is not possible then. :(

Comment: You could ship vanilla, unmodified, ffmpeg, with due attribution in your documents, or a link to download it if it is missing and use it in the back-end processing but if it is a commercial product you are still likely to run into the same issues.

Comment: Hmm, thought so. Not only attribution (which we don't have any problem with, we have to do it with Boost or MIT license as well), we have to include the source code separately as well. That is annoying.

Comment: If you are calling it externally and unmodified you don't have to include YOUR source code, only make the FFMPEG source __available__.

Comment: Yes yes, that is what I meant - including FFMPEG's source code. What do you mean by calling it externally?

Comment: If rather than building FFMPEG into your code as a library you use `os.exec` to execute it with whatever options you need just as if it being used from the command line.

Comment: Yes, we want that only. We just want to use it from our application as a command line tool..So how is that any different from building it into our app as a library?

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me whether the FFMPEG license prohibits me from packing it with my app as a separate independent binary (to be invoked from within code as a separate process that uses that binary)? Our EULA will also specify that we are using FFMPEG..

Comment: My reading of the licence suggests that it does, you should also include a link to the ffmpeg site as this counts as making the source code available, __but__ I am not a lawyer in my country let alone internationally, (than heavens), so I could be mistaken.  If you have concerns then contact one or all of ffmpeg team, free software foundation or good lawyer - _personally I would go for the first two_!

Comment: Yep, I will do that for sure.. :) If it is about linking to their site in our license agreement window, we are totally fine with it. Hope they don't ask us to include their source code as well!